# FlexibleSearchQuery response no data

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to get some data using `FlexibleSearchQuery` but it is responding empty result. If I set this query `hac>Console>Flexible Search`  I can get the data I am looking for.
Here is how I am writing query in java file.

```
sb.append(" SELECT {p:pk} ");
        sb.append(" FROM {" + ProductModel._TYPECODE + " AS p} ");
        sb.append(" WHERE {p:" + ProductModel.PK + " } IN ({{");
        sb.append(" SELECT DISTINCT {pro:" + ProductModel.PK + "} ");
        sb.append(" FROM {CategoryProductRelation AS cp},{" + ProductModel._TYPECODE + "! AS pro},{" + CategoryModel._TYPECODE
                + " AS c}");
        sb.append(" WHERE {pro:" + ProductModel.PK + " } = {cp:target}");
        sb.append("  AND {c:" + CategoryModel.PK + " } = {cp:source}");
        sb.append("  AND {c:" + CategoryModel.CODE + " } !=?categoryCode    }})");



args.put("categoryCode", categoryCode);

if (args != null && !args.isEmpty())
{
            searchQuery.addQueryParameters(args);
}
```

Here is how I call search

```
final FlexibleSearchQuery searchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(sb.toString());

searchResult.getResult().size()  >> retuns 0
```

If I type it in console

```
SELECT {p:pk} FROM { Product AS p} WHERE { p: pk } IN ({{ 

            SELECT DISTINCT {pro: PK } 

                  FROM 

            {CategoryProductRelation AS cp}, 
            {Product AS pro}, 
            {Category as c} 

            WHERE {pro: PK} = {cp:target}

            AND {c:PK} = {cp:source}
            AND {c:code} != '0101'}})
```

I get

```
PK
8796093579265
8796101804033
8796100165633
8796098428929
8796093153281
8796102361089
8796097052673
8796093808641
8796093972481
8796096823297
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any difference console query and string query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem in your case is related to Restrections, by definition : Restrictions are rules obeyed by FlexibleSearch which allow to limit search results depending on which type is searched and which user is currently logged in

so try to Disable search restrictions before calling your flexible seach

```
import de.hybris.platform.search.restriction.SearchRestrictionService;
...
// Disable search restrictions
searchRestrictionService.disableSearchRestrictions();
// some query goes here

// Enable search restrictions
searchRestrictionService.enableSearchRestrictions();
// some query goes here
```

In other hand , when you use `hac>Console>Flexible Search` i suppose that you log as admin , so all restrictions are disabled by default in Hybris Flexible search

You can check all actives restrctions in HMC, by searchig the type : `SearchRestriction` , look the followinf screenshot

[image]

see : https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c428f8286691014970ceee87aa01605.html

Comment: Answer from Guillaume A. is better because disabling restrictions in service has impact on all currently running code and might cause security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to bypass restriction is to use sessionService to execute

`sessionService.executeInLocalView(new SessionExecutionBody() {
                            @Override
                            public void executeWithoutResult() {
                                // do stuff
                            }
                        }, userService.getAdminUser());`

I find this solution more elegant. :-)

Comment: From a security perspective this is the better answer because it does not have issues on parallel running code as it would have if you disable restrictions in service.